# Turn off reprompt response in a python Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an lambda-based Alexa skill and I want to turn off reprompting. I know I should set the reprompt text to something, but I can't seem to find it on SO or in the Amazon documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found this while writing the question:
https://gist.github.com/n8henrie/3db1205331d0f6195b01#file-alexa-skills-kit-color-expert-python-py-L144

Looks like you should `reprompt_text = None`

This does mean that you should now handle the result in the function:

`def on_session_ended(session_ended_request, session):`

for those of us using the pre-built lambda functions.